# Using `os.system("")` opening new window and cmd on button click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button, cmd, pyinstaller

I have an issue where I use the `os.system(")` function to open a different script but on button click it opens the script and cmd. The script is written as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os

master = Tk()
master.title("Manufacturing")
master.config(bg="skyblue3")

l1 = Label(master, text="Reflex Footwear (Pty) Ltd", font=["Calibri, bold", 20])
l1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=N, pady=2)


def tkinter1():
    ret = os.system('python C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SoftwareTest\orders.py')
    if ret:
        exit()


def tkinter2():
    ret = os.system('python C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SoftwareTest\handlacing.py')
    if ret:
        exit()


def tkinter3():
    ret = os.system('python C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SoftwareTest\stock_sheet.py')
    if ret:
        exit()


def tkinter4():
    ret = os.system('python C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SoftwareTest\logistics_view.py')
    if ret:
        exit()


def tkinter5():
    ret = os.system('python C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SoftwareTest\bill.py')
    if ret:
        exit()


def tkinter6():
    ret = os.system('python C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SoftwareTest\production.py')
    if ret:
        exit()

# Images
img = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\sig.png")
img1 = img.subsample(1, 1)

img = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Buttons\exit.png")
img2 = img.subsample(2, 2)

img = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Buttons\orders_in_house.png")
img3 = img.subsample(2, 2)

img = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Buttons\handlacing.png")
img4 = img.subsample(2, 2)

img = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Buttons\stock_in_house.png")
img5 = img.subsample(2, 2)

img = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Buttons\logistics.png")
img6 = img.subsample(2, 2)

img = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Buttons\bom.png")
img7 = img.subsample(2, 2)

img = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Buttons\production.png")
img8 = img.subsample(2, 2)

# Setting image in label
Label(master, image=img1).grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, rowspan=8, padx=20, pady=30)

# Buttons
# b1 = Button(master, text="Order In House", command=tkinter1)
b1 = Button(master, image=img3, command=tkinter1)
# b2 = Button(master, text="Handlacing", command=tkinter2)
b2 = Button(master, image=img4, command=tkinter2)
# b3 = Button(master, text="Stock In House", command=tkinter3)
b3 = Button(master, image=img5, command=tkinter3)
# b4 = Button(master, text="Logistics", command=tkinter4)
b4 = Button(master, image=img6, command=tkinter4)
# b5 = Button(master, text="Bill Of Materials", command=tkinter5)
b5 = Button(master, image=img7, command=tkinter5)
# b6 = Button(master, text="Production", command=tkinter6)
b6 = Button(master, image=img8, command=tkinter6)
# b7 = Button(master, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
b7 = Button(master, image=img2, command=master.destroy)

# Arranging Buttons
b1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W + N)
b2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W + N)
b3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W + N)
b4.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W + N)
b5.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W + N)
b6.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W + N)
b7.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W + N)

mainloop()
```

Every time I click the button it opens a new window.
I am wondering if there is a way, other than to reprogram every script, if there is a way to not have the cmd open on every button click.

When I compiled this script with `pyinstaller` I used `--onefile --windowed` and `--onefile` too see if the result may give me the option to not have cmd pop up every time I click a button.

I want to end up with a window that opens with the `.exe` file created, then when I click the button it only opens the selected window/script on top, instead of opening cmd and then only the next/other script.

I hope that this could be accomplished.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking, but it would make much more sense to have each of those Python scripts as modules that you `import` (or even just have one module containing them all if the code in each is small), then you can just call a function from the module to do whatever. I'd only do it like you are if you absolutely cannot change the other code.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I am hoping that you would be able to help me with another possible solution. I am wondering if i can use `ttk.Notebook` to have the tabs view different scripts with respective buttons and treeview, instead of running them individually. Then import all of the scripts and run them in the notebook?